# Samsung Galaxy A10 asks for password after update to Android 11

Tags: samsung, locked-out

After updating my Samsung Galaxy A10 to Android 11, I get the message "your password contains at least 4 characters, including at least one letter" so I can't unlock my phone's screen. I didn't set any password before, I had a swipe lock. I want to copy all data to the computer and then do a hard reset (I have password to google account so FRP won't be a problem).

I tried to unlock my phone and backup to Samsung Cloud via Samsung Find My Mobile but remote unlock is disabled.

When I connect my phone to my computer, file explorer doesn't detect my phone (I can't enable MTP mode).

USB debugging is disabled

Entering default_password also didn't help (maybe it's new default password for Galaxy A10?)

Is there any way to copy all data to computer or unlock my phone without losing data?